# Inner join 3 fields from 1st table with the same field in 2nd table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table1 (mtrlines) where 3 different columns containing the ID from the table1 (prsn). I need to select the name2 from table2 instead of ID

Running the query only for 1 column it works and returns the information correct:
i.e.

```
SELECT ['Ins.'].NAME2 AS ['Ins.']
FROM MTRLINES
INNER JOIN PRSN AS ['Ins.'] ON MTRLINES.CCCTABLE01 = ['Ins.'].PRSN
WHERE MTRLINES.FINDOC = 22648
```

I get the correct result:
Line1: FL
Line2: FL
Line3: GP

but when trying to combine more columns it returns empty values
i.e.

```
SELECT ['Ins.'].NAME2 AS ['Ins.'], ['Ins.1'].NAME2 AS ['Ins.1']
FROM MTRLINES
INNER JOIN PRSN AS ['Ins.'] ON MTRLINES.CCCTABLE01 = ['Ins.'].PRSN
INNER JOIN PRSN AS ['Ins.1'] ON MTRLINES.CCCTABLE02 = ['Ins.1'].PRSN
WHERE MTRLINES.FINDOC = 22648
```

Returns null values.

How can I will get the information below ?

Head: Ins.| Ins.1
Line1:  FL| EA
Line2:  FL| RT
Line3:  GP| EA

Where FL, EA, etc are the values from name2 columns of prsn table.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  And there are no `NULL` values in the example you give.

Comment: _Columns_, not fields.

Comment: Thank you jarlh for the correction !

Answer (score 0):

You don't say much about your database and the requirements. But given the Query and the result, it looks like you don't have any combinations of MTRLINES.FINDOC=22648 and two matching rows in PRSN table.

If you change your joins to LEFT OUTER joins instead, you'll see if you get any matches at all. So something like this:

```
SELECT ['Ins.'].NAME2 AS ['Ins.'], ['Ins.1'].NAME2 AS ['Ins.1']
FROM MTRLINES
LEFT OUTER JOIN PRSN AS ['Ins.'] ON MTRLINES.CCCTABLE01 = ['Ins.'].PRSN
LEFT OUTER JOIN PRSN AS ['Ins.1'] ON MTRLINES.CCCTABLE02 = ['Ins.1'].PRSN
WHERE MTRLINES.FINDOC = 22648
```

And to make the result a bit more readable, at least while you're developing, add a column from MTRLINES table to the SELECT-list as well.
If you want only rows where there's *at least* one corresponding row in PRSN table, you could add a predicate to the WHERE clause:

```
AND EXISTS(SELECT ['INS.'].Name2, ['INS.1'].Name2 EXCEPT SELECT NULL,NULL)
```